# Visualise Nginx's location block parsing during development?

Tags: nginx

Is there a way to visualise how Nginx is interpreting Location blocks?
This is for during development and not for production.
I was wondering if there is a specialised module for getting access to this info or is parsing the log files the only way. 
I'm sure some network monitoring tools would do this but they are focused on performance monitoring so it is difficult to know which would help for this simple requirement. 
Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by visualize? You could turn on debug logs

Comment: I have, but they are too verbose. Visualise, such as  a graph, a tree structure or at least a simplified list in a Terminal.